# Kubeflow jupyter notebook created, but no notebook resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm new to Kubeflow and having hard time debugging.

I created a notebook server with a custom dockerhub image, and when I click on 'connect', it says that there is no healthy upstream. In Home, I found that there exist activities, and it says back-off restarting failed container.

Where should I find the detailed logs with kubectl?

Also, I'm quite confused due to notebooks crd. I have successfully setup another notebook server with the image offered by Kubeflow itself (the official images they provide), but there exist no notebooks crd in my kubeflow namespace.

Wrapping the question up, I'm curious about how to find the detailed logs about the activities. Next, I'm curious why no notebooks crd exist though I have notebook server successfully deployed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/notebooks/troubleshoot/) guide? Did you try `kubectl describe pod ${NOTEBOOK}-0 ? What did you already try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was looking at a wrong namespace. I'm closing the question.